# Java 11: Programmatically compiling code using JavaCompiler is slow

Tags: java, java-11

Getting very slow JavaCompiler compile time.

I recently switched from Java8 to Java11. Since then I sporadically get a very slow compilation time. I want to know if anybody else has encountered this problem.

I am only seeing slow JavaCompiler questions around Java8, but I didn't encounter any issues since I switch to Java11.

```
    JavaFileManager fileManager = javac.getStandardFileManager(null, Locale.getDefault(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = javac.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, options, null, compilationUnits);
    boolean result = task.call();
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling?

Comment: The problem is that it happens every now and then. I didn't manage to catch it with a profiler.

Comment: @MaraisKruger how about writing a test case and/or a benchmark to run compilation multiple times with some local profiling and see what's the output? Problem is likely environment related.